# Why does ui.alert work but ui.prompt does not with onOpen()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I use onOpen(), I can create a popup ui.alert but ui.prompt does not work.

For example:

```
 function onOpen() {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // get ui for alert
 ui.alert('Hello!')
     }
```

works but:

```
 function onOpen() {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // get ui for alert
 var nname = ui.prompt('What is your name?', 'E.G.: J Smith', ui.ButtonSet.OK)
             }
```

does not!

Has anyone else found this issue? Am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks,

G

Edit:

If I run both like this, the ui.alert works but the ui.prompt does nothing. If I debug the function, both work.

```
function onOpen() { 
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // get ui for alert 
ui.alert('Hello!') 
var nname = ui.prompt('What is your name?', 'E.G.: J Smith', ui.ButtonSet.OK); 
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting in the browser's developer console?

Comment: I get no error, just nothing happens when I run it. I tried running ui.alert and ui.prompt consecutively and one showed up and the other did not. Interestingly, if I run the function the ui.alert works and the ui.prompt does not. If I debug the function, both work!

Comment: This is the code:

`code` function onOpen() {
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // get ui for alert
 
 ui.alert('Hello!')
 var nname = ui.prompt('What is your name?', 'E.G.: J Smith', ui.ButtonSet.OK);

}

Comment: In your code do you have 2 seperate `onOpen()` functions when you try this or just one?

Comment: Just one, as above, but I have tried it on its own too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a permission restriction of the simple `onOpen` trigger.

If you check the execution transcript of the code using the prompt you will see `Execution failed: You do not have permission to call prompt (line 3, file "____________") [0.001 seconds total runtime]`

If you want this to work you need to use an installed trigger. Have a read of a previous answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155847/google-script-project-trigger-not-running/45157034#45157034), it's about the `onSubmit` trigger in Forms but you just need to change to an `onOpen` trigger and then your script will work as you want it to.

Comment: No problem, glad to be able to help!