# onEdit Google script is not getting called

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted to execute a function whenever a cell is edited or added in google spreadsheet.

I have the below function, but it is not working. please help. Also I wanted to call the function Start sync after X seconds. How to give a delay in calling the startSync()

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
  startSync()
}
```

---

whenever I edit a cell , a note (comment) is getting added to the cell , but the startSync is not getting called.

```
function startSync() {
  //Get the currently active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //Get the number of rows and columns which contain some content
  var [rows, columns] = [sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()];
  //Get the data contained in those rows and columns as a 2 dimensional array
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows, columns).getValues();

  syncMasterSheet(data);
}
```

Answer:
Installable Triggers helped me to call StartSync()

Comment: What services does the `startSync` call stack invoke? If any require authorization - such as opening a different spreadsheet document - then you cannot use a simple trigger.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a simple `onEdit`trigger with most `.set` methods. You need to use an installed `onEdit()` trigger instead. [See this answer for more information on triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155847/google-script-project-trigger-not-running/45157034#45157034)

To delay the start of the function use `Utilities.sleep(milliseconds)` before the call to the `startSync()` function. See more info about the `Utilities` class [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer))

Comment: setNote works fine with a simple onEdit trigger.

Comment: Custom functions are the ones with the inability to call most `.set*`