# Apps Script not sending email with MailApp.sendEmail()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have code wherein when I select a checkbox in column 'N', it should send an email. It goes through the pass1, pass2 and pass3 alerts but after that, nothing. It worked when I tried to run the script in the script editor by replacing the selRow and selCol variables with a hardcoded number value.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var selRow = e.range.getRow();
  var selCol = e.range.getColumn();

  var activeWS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Active');
  var closeWS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Closed');

  if(activeWS.getRange(selRow, selCol).getValue() == true && selCol == 14){

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('pass 1');

    // Fetch the email address
    var emailAddress = 'sample@gmail.com';
    var subjPart = activeWS.getRange(selRow, 2).getValue();

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('pass2');

    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Please visit www.sample.com to view the latest project ready for Cap Out';
    var subject = 'Roofing Project ' + subjPart + 'is ready for Cap Out';
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('pass3');
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress , subject, message);

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Email sent');

  }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether my understanding of your situation is correct, I think that if you try to run `onEdit` by the simple trigger, an error occurs at `MailApp.sendEmail`. Because in this case, it is required to authorize. So how about using the installable OnEdit event trigger and testing it again? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) At that time, please rename the function name for avoiding the duplicate execution of the function. If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: As Tanaike said, are you using a simple or installed trigger? [Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155847/google-script-project-trigger-not-running/45157034#45157034)

Comment: Tanaike's solution is right. I switched to installable trigger and change the name of my onEdit function. It worked! Thanks Tanaike. How can i mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve your issue, I would like to propose to use the installable OnEdit event trigger. When you run the function of `onEdit` as the simple trigger, an error occurs at `MailApp.sendEmail`, because in this case, it is required to authorize.

As an important point, please rename the function name of `onEdit` to others. By this, the duplicate execution of the function can be avoided. For example, when `onEdit` is installed as the installable OnEdit event trigger, when a cell is edited, `onEdit` is run by both the simple trigger and the installable trigger. So in this case, it is required to rename the function name from `onEdit` to others. This can be seen at [this report](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5).

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Asynchronous Processing using Event Triggers](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5)